# A long text in the TextView

Tags: android, textview, longtext

I have a button, and when i click to it, i make `textView.setText()` a very big text, 50000 symbols, and the interface stops for 3 seconds, how can i fix it?

1. I tried to make it with Handle and thread, but it hasn`t helped.
2. I tried to make `textview.append()`, but it also hasn`t helped.

   ```
               MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {

                   textText.append(rowItemHeader.getText().substring((endOfNews - 10000, endOfNews));
               }
           });
   ```

   Edit 1 no result

`private class MyTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {
        String str;
        TextView txt;`

```
    MyTask(String str, TextView txt){
        this.str = str;
        this.txt = txt;

    }
    public String doInBackground(Void... args) {

        return str.substring(endOfNews - 10000, endOfNews);
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String myString) {
        // do your update here or you will get that error (the original thread one)
        txt.append(myString);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Is the variable `myString` correctly elaborated?

Comment: its working, but i have delay for 1-3 seconds, when i click to button. If i have small text, it works fast, but if i have very larege text, i have delay.

Comment: Ok, but have you fixed this with the AsyncTask?

Comment: No, everything is the same, i append 10000 symbols, and i think that setText() and append() works very slow with big text. So, I cant do it in background, i need to do it On Ui Thread :(

Answer (score 0):

How did you declare the thread ? 
Yu've to use something like that :

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("TAG synchronize", "synchronize");
        }
});
```

Comment: I did like that, but it also stops interface for 1-3 seconds :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), they are meant for exactly what you want. They are a secondary thread that is easy to setup and executes from your main thread.

Use a loop inside the thread that `appends` portions of the generated text to the `TextView` using `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(...)...)` and call `Thread.sleep(50)` which forces the Thread to sleep for that much milliseconds to prevent the lag.

Comment: If i do with AsyncTask i have error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: Then you didn't do it fully, you didn't do the `runOnUiThread()` that makes it "run on the ui thread"! Only `appending` should be "run on the ui thread" don't put the entire `AsyncTask` operations to run on the ui as that would make it freeze as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AyncTask with something like:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Context context;       

    public MyTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // do your job here
        return myString;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String myString) {
        // do your update here or you will get that error (the original thread one)
        ((TextView)context.findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText(myString);
    }
}
```

and then in your activity

```
new MyTask(MyActivity.this).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the view, then add the text on background thread, then add the view back. Tell me if you need some sample code.